# Custom Loss involving multivariate normal in keras

Tags: loss-function, loss, tf.keras

I need to implement a loss function whereby it takes in some true y that is a 4 dimensional vector and computes the probability of this vector under some normal distribution. I tried to build the probability density function using the keras.backend functions but there doesnt seem to be anything for matrix inverses? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [`tensorflow_probability`](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability) package. In particular the [`tfp.distributions.Normal.prob()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/Normal#prob) method should return you the probability of an input tensor under the specified normal distribution.

You can see some examples of such computations [in this Jupyter notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/examples/jupyter_notebooks/TensorFlow_Distributions_Tutorial.ipynb). Multivariate Gaussians and mixtures of Gaussians are also supported, as well as many other distributions.